# ADFS0112E: File transfer has failed - Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I'm getting an `UnknownHostException` when using the the AdminClient from the WebSphere client SDK to remotely install an EAR file.

Is there anyway to skip Hostname checking for AdminClient? or force AdminClient to use IP only.

Is's likely an issue with our company DNS but not something I can configure.

Full exception:

```
2016-11-17 10:53:08 [main] ERROR c.i.w.m.f.c.FileTransferClientImpl - ADFS0112E: File transfer has failed with the following message: Upload retry limit exceeded for file my.ear. Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: MYHOST
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: Failure uploading archive to server
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementProxy.uploadArchive(AppManagementProxy.java:732)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementProxy.installApplication(AppManagementProxy.java:528)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.filetransfer.client.TransferFailedException: Upload retry limit exceeded for file my.ear. Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: MYHOST
    at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.client.FileTransferClientImpl.uploadFileInternal(FileTransferClientImpl.java:595)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.client.FileTransferClientImpl.uploadFile(FileTransferClientImpl.java:462)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.client.FileTransferClientImpl.uploadFile(FileTransferClientImpl.java:369)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.client.FileTransferClientImpl.uploadFile(FileTransferClientImpl.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.copyToServer(AppInstallHelper.java:1245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementProxy.uploadArchive(AppManagementProxy.java:718)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: MYHOST
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.client.FileTransferClientImpl.connectToServer(FileTransferClientImpl.java:2947)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.client.FileTransferClientImpl.openConnection(FileTransferClientImpl.java:2859)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.client.FileTransferClientImpl.uploadFileInternal(FileTransferClientImpl.java:547)
```

Comment: Can you add an entry to your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: @DarVar: I am getting the same error, have you fixed this yet ?

Comment: @AlexandrePolozoff: Do you mean add to /etc/hosts on the remote server ? The file included 10.53.252.15 tt35app.xxxx.com tt35app ssp-test.xxx.com, but still got error: com.ibm.ws.management.filetransfer.client.FileTransferClientImpl
SEVERE: ADFS0112E: File transfer has failed with the following message: Upload retry limit exceeded for file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\QLKLKHT\QLLKHTEAR.ear. Exception: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <tt35app.xxxx.com>.

Comment: @AlexandrePolozoff: My code build is: My code build is: <target name="uninstallEAR">
  <taskdef name="wsUninstallApp" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.UninstallApplication" classpath="${was_cp}"/>
  <wsUninstallApp application="{ear.name}"
   washome="${was_home}"
   host="10.53.252.15" profileName="AppSrv01" port="8880" conntype="SOAP" user="admin" password="xxxx" 
   failonerror="false" />
 </target>